# Write text onto image in Java

Tags: java, image-manipulation

Is there a Java library to write text to images, same as PHP's [GD library](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php).

Answer (score 37):

Try the below code

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Testing {
    public static void main(String arg[]) throws IOException {
        String key = "Sample";
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(170, 30,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics graphics = bufferedImage.getGraphics();
        graphics.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 50);
        graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        graphics.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 20));
        graphics.drawString(key, 10, 25);
        ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", new File(
                "C:/Users/admin/desktop/image.jpg"));
        System.out.println("Image Created");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Sure.  First load the image, probably using a method of `ImageIO`. Then, using a `Graphics` object representing the image itself, call the `drawString` method.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Graphics2D.drawString](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.awt/Graphics2DdrawStringStringstrintxinty.htm)